# How to check if non-chrome window is focused Chrome Extensions API

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm working on a chrome extension that tracks the active chrome tab and chrome window, but I want it to know when the active window is a non-chrome window.

When using a listener for `chrome.windows.onFocusChanged`, the listener only triggers when the new focused window is a chrome window or if all chrome windows are minimized. It does not trigger if you maximize or alt-tab into another non-chrome window. Is there a solution for this or is this problem out of scope for the Chrome Extensions API?

Comment: You'll have to write a separate utility that monitors the focus change and communicate with it via [nativeMessaging](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/nativeMessaging).

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved (partially) with the [Page Visibility API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Page_Visibility_API). `document.visibilityState` will return the value of `hidden` when the current tab is covered by another maximized program window, or when the tab is not visible.

You can add this to your content scripts:

```
var string = document.visibilityState;
```

Or as an event listener:

```
document.addEventListener("visibilitychange", function() {
  console.log( document.visibilityState );
  // Modify behavior...
})
```

Unfortunately, `document.visibilityState` is not accurate for all programs I've tested (such as Steam or Windows Settings), and it will only return the value of `hidden` when the chrome tab is completely covered from view, not partially.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with `onFocusChanged` event

```
chrome.windows.onFocusChanged.addListener(function (windowId) {
  if (windowId === chrome.windows.WINDOW_ID_NONE) {
    chrome.tabs.query({ active: true, currentWindow: true }, function (tabs) {
      //because sometimes, Chrome dispatches the event switching tabs, which you
      //don't want
      if (tabs.length === 0) {
        //here, you switched from Chrome to another app
      }
    });
  }
});
```